# Solving for a variable

Tags: linear-algebra

> For what values of $a$ the angle between the vectors $[1, 2, 1]^T$ and $[1, 0, a]^T$ is equal to $\cos60^{\circ}?$

Let $u = [1, 2, 1]^T$ and $v = [1, 0, a]^T$.  Then $u \cdot v = 1 + a$ and $\|u\| \|v\| = \sqrt 6  \sqrt{1 + a^2}$.

$\frac12 = \cos60^{\circ} = \frac {u \cdot v} {\|u\|\|v\|} =  \frac {1 + a} {\sqrt 6 \sqrt{1 + a^2}}$

$\frac{\sqrt 6 \sqrt{1 + a^2}}{2} = {1 + a} $

$\frac{6 (1 + a^2)}{4} = (1 + a)^2$

$\frac {3 + 3a^2}{2} = 1 + 2a + 4a^2$

$3 + 3a^2 = 2 + 4a + 8a^2$

$0 = 5a^2 + 4a - 1$

$0 = (a + 1)(5a - 1)$

Let $a = \frac 15$.

Assuming the above is correct, what's the most efficient way to solve for $a$? If not correct, what's the best way to solve this problem?

edit:

$\frac {3 + 3a^2}{2} = 1 + 2a + a^2$

$3 + 3a^2 = 2 + 4a + 2a^2$

$1 + a^2 - 4a = 0$

$a = 2 - \sqrt3$ or $a = 2 + \sqrt 3$.

I am not sure if I am tripping or what, but neither of these $a$ seem to be suitable.

edit 2:

Here's a mess. Doe it look remotely close to truth?

$\frac 12 = \frac {3 + \sqrt 3}{\sqrt 6 (1 + 2 + 2 \sqrt 3 + 3)} = \frac {3 + \sqrt 3}{\sqrt 6 (6 + 2 \sqrt 3)} = \frac {3 + \sqrt 3}{2(3\sqrt6 + \sqrt 3)} = \frac {3 + \sqrt 3}{2(3\sqrt3 \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)}$

edit 3:

More explicitly,

If $u, v$ are the given vectors:

$u \cdot v = 3 + \sqrt 3$

$\|u\|\|v\| = \sqrt 6 \sqrt{1 + (2 + \sqrt 3)^2} = \sqrt 6 \sqrt{1 + 4 + 4\sqrt 3 + 3} = \sqrt 6 \sqrt{8 + 4\sqrt 3} = 2 \sqrt 6 \sqrt{(2 + \sqrt 3)}$

Still a mess.

Comment: check the step when you had expanded (1+a)^2

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my OP.

Comment: now why this a doesn't seems suitable to you

Comment: I updated my OP again. Do you agree?

Comment: you didn't expand a^2 correctly

Comment: check it once again

Comment: I did another update :)  I am terrible at elementary algebraic manipulations.

Comment: It is not a mess now, it is done. Problem is in simplifying our R.H.S., do one thing square it and simplify it , you will get 1/4 as your answer which is simply square of 1/2

Comment: Thank you. I'll choose your answer as the best one if you answer this thread with anything.